# Unity sizeDelta height returns incorrect value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this RectTransform:

[image]

Its part of my hover GUI. Everytime I hover over something the GUI is filled with information (because of this the height is dynamic) and moved to the object I hover over.

Sometimes the GUI is offscreen and to move it back into view I need to know the current height.

In the image above is an example, there the current height is 545.01, but my script logs a different height:

```
RectTransform hoverElementRect = instance.hoverGUI.GetComponent<HoverGUI_Components>().GetHoverElement().GetComponent<RectTransform>();

Debug.Log(hoverElementRect.sizeDelta); // gives (450, 842)
```

How is this possible?

I leave it for now without too much code, I am a newb in unity and maybe someone already has an idea, [but here is the whole GUI postioning and creating code](https://pastebin.com/1yzSHFu0).

The relevant part is at the end.

EDIT:

```
foreach (RectTransform rect in instance.hoverGUI.GetComponent<HoverGUI_Components>().GetHoverElement().GetComponentsInChildren<RectTransform>()) {
    LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(rect);
    rect.ForceUpdateRectTransforms();
}

RectTransform hoverElementRect = instance.hoverGUI.GetComponent<HoverGUI_Components>().GetHoverElement().GetComponent<RectTransform>();

LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(hoverElementRect);
hoverElementRect.ForceUpdateRectTransforms();
```

ForceUpdateRectTransforms() does not cahnge anything. I have even used it on all rects in the whole GUI object. I even tried to use it after each operation I have done.

Comment: Likely `local` vs. `global`

Comment: `sizeDelta` as the name says is a local delta offset to the parent object. rather try using `Debug.Log(hoverElementRect.rect.width + ", " + hoverElementRect.rect.height);` which afaik should return the absolute sizes.

Comment: I Check this method and it returns same value for me so Maybe this is not that RectTransform and your code gets another RectTransform. define a public RectTransform field and set it in unity editor and check its sizeDelta to see what is going on. or print the name of its GameObject .

Comment: SizeDelta Description: The size of this RectTransform relative to the distances between the anchors.
If the anchors are together, sizeDelta is the same as size. If the anchors are in each of the four corners of the parent, the sizeDelta is how much bigger or smaller the rectangle is compared to its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your specific issue by using `LayoutUtility.GetPreferredHeight(rectTransform)`. Don't force update anything.

Here's an extension method that may be helpful generally. You may need to reorder the checks for your specific application.

```
public static class RectTransformExtension
    {
        /// <summary>Sometimes sizeDelta works, sometimes rect works, sometimes neither work and you need to get the layout properties.
        /// This method provides a simple way to get the size of a RectTransform, no matter what's driving it or what the anchor values are.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rectTransform">The rect transform to check.</param>
        /// <returns>The proper size of the RectTransform.</returns>
        public static Vector2 GetProperSize(this RectTransform rectTransform) //, bool attemptToRefreshLayout = false)
        {
            Vector2 size = new Vector2(rectTransform.rect.width, rectTransform.rect.height);

            if (size.x == 0 && size.y == 0)
            {
                size.x = LayoutUtility.GetPreferredWidth(rectTransform);
                size.y = LayoutUtility.GetPreferredHeight(rectTransform);
            }

            if (size.x == 0 && size.y == 0)
            {
                LayoutGroup layoutGroup = rectTransform.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>();

                if (layoutGroup != null)
                {
                    size.x = layoutGroup.preferredWidth;
                    size.y = layoutGroup.preferredHeight;
                }
            }


            return size;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sizeDelta you call in the awake method and the sizeDelta you call in the start method may produce different results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33376050)

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, always use

```
hoverElementRect.rect.size
```

instead of

```
hoverElementRect.sizeDelta
```

Comment: rect.size gives me the same values... well I have no clue were the problem could be.

Answer (score -2):

I know that this question is already old but I'll share my simple solution anyway: Make sure that you have added "using UnityEngine.UI" namespace to your script. Otherwise, RectTransform.sizeDelta will return a wrong value.